# Bash script: fork based on currest ISP

Tags: bash

I would like a script that does one thing if I am on campus (University of Waterloo), and another thing if I am not. How can I determine my ISP, or anything else equivalent, from a bash script so that I can put it into a reliable if-else statement?

(I am running Ubuntu. If you are curious, my application is starting up commercial software on a server license and the script needs to know whether to start a proxy or not.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One options would be to look at your public IP address. A common way to determine that is to do something like the following:

```
my_ip=$(wget -qO - http://whatismyip.org/)
```

Likely that's enough info for you to do what you want. Or, you could pass it along to `whois` and grab the NetName field, or some other identifiable field.

Comment: Awesome, thanks this is perfect. I can run `netname=$(whois $my_ip | grep NetName | cut -d: -f 2 | sed 's/^ *//')` to get the network name.

Answer (score 1):

First, proxies suck.  If it's not mandatory... get rid of it.  Second, the real question is... how does your computer know what network it's attached to?  IP address?  Default gateway?  MAC address of the gateway?  voodoo?

Once you can answer the 2nd question, building a bash script is a trivial matter.  IP address can be parsed from `ifconfig` ... default gateway can be parsed from `route`... mac address of default gateway can be parsed from a mix of `ping` and `arp`... (need to resolve the ip first... then arp will have an entry for it).  etc...

Answer (score 1):

The simplest will be to check the subnet you are in:

```
/sbin/ifconfig -a | sed -n '/Mask/ {/127.0.0.1/! p}'
```

but in the worst scenario, where everything is the same, you could just trace the route to something and compare the first jumps. Store those values and then just compare them

```
#at uni
$ traceroute stackoverflow.com | sed -n '2,5 s/[ 1-9]*\([^ ]*\) .*/\1/ p' > uni

#at home
$ traceroute stackoverflow.com | sed -n '2,5 s/[ 1-9]*\([^ ]*\) .*/\1/ p' > home

#then when you want just check
diff uni <(traceroute stackoverflow.com | sed -n '2,5 s/[ 1-9]*\([^ ]*\) .*/\1/ p' > location1)
```

The exit status of the diff will tell you if it matches or not. This will work in 90% of the cases, for the rest you'll have to tune the 2,5 paramer there which extracts the jumps 1 to 4. To be honest 1 is enough, but if you have multiple accesspoints you might want to compare for the 2nd or 3rd... just check the results of traceroute visually and decide what would be required.

And don't forget to compare for both uni and home, since you might find things changing and you would just want to know this happened instead of picking a default one.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with bash scripts, but in terms of detecting which ISP you're on you could use your ip address/subnet along with a config file of some kind. You could then change the comfig file without having to change the code to tell which network you're on.